# I can't log in to launchpad

Tags: bug-reporting, launchpad

I'm trying to file a bug report but I cannot login to launchpad. I don't know if there is some kind of maintenance going on but I can't login. I already logged in to my Ubuntu one account but still does not let me login to launchpad to report the bug. This is what the page shows me after I try to login. [Opss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i49kg.png) If anyone knows how to solve this problem let me know please because the bug that I am experiencing is related to external drives. They freezes the whole system and is has been there for a while.  By the way I already tried using the Ubuntu-bug tool, but it does not work either.

Comment: Well I tried to log in to IRC channels, I tried the options shown at the image and still I can't log in to my launchpad account. I followed the links they gave me and still nothing.

Comment: Launchpad is currently up and working properly.

Comment: Same problem here. I had an account years ago with an old email. I registered yesterday with a new email, but I have been unable to log in so far. I get always an "oops" error.